# DataTable - Row against "each row"

Tags: javascript

can anybody explain me why the following code works properly

```
aDataTable.find('tbody').find('tr').each(function() {
    var rowItems = $(this).children();
});
```

while the following

```
var rowItems = aDataTable.find('tbody').find('tr')[0].children();
```

reports the error:

> "aDataTable.find(...).find(...)[0].children is not a function"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$(this)` is a jQuery object

`aDataTable.find('tbody').find('tr')[0]` return an [`Element`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Element)

like if you were doing `this.children()` in the first function

you can use the function [`eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) to get a jQuery object

`aDataTable.find('tbody').find('tr').eq(0).children()`

Comment: Wonderful Hacketo! How can I solve to make the second example work?

Comment: You can use `eq` as stated in the post